# Gutenberg blocks: RichText default value displaying HTML tags

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

When I include  tags in the following Gutenberg block it outputs the HTML tags in both the editor and the frontend. This is only happening with default text-- when adding a link from within the editor it renders correctly:

```
attributes: {
  text: {
    type: 'array',
    source: 'children',
    selector: 'p',
    default: 'Here is the test <a href="https://example.com">link</a>',
  },
}

edit: ({ attributes: { text }, setText ) => {
  return <RichText
    placeholder="Text..."
    tagName="p"
    onChange={setText}
    value={text}
    allowedFormats={['core/bold', 'core/italic', 'core/link']}
  />
}

save: () => {
  return <RichText.Content tagName="p" value={text} />
}
```

Outputs (wrapped in `<p>` tag):

```
Here is the test <a href="https://example.com">link</a>
```

Have tried copying markup from the Gutenberg core/link exactly:

```
default: 'Here is the test <a href="https://example.com">link</a>'
```

Outputs (wrapped in `<p>` tag):

```
Here is the test <a href="https://example.com">link</a>
```

And have tried setting the default text with the tag as an object:

```
default: `Here is the test ${<a href="https://example.com">link</a>}`
```

Outputs (wrapped in `<p>` tag):

```
Here is the test [object Object]
```

How can I get this default text to output the tags themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [RichText](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/richtext/) component [placeholder text](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/block-editor/src/components/rich-text/README.md#placeholder-string) supports plain text only. However, you can add preformatted content like links and other supported formatting by defining example content within the block properties:

```
...
attributes: {
    text: {
        type: 'array',
        source: 'html',
        selector: 'p'
    },
},
example: {
    attributes: {
        text: 'Here is the test <a href="https://example.com">link</a>'
    }
},
...
```

By defining the example attribute, `placeholder= ...` and `default: ...` are no longer needed and the 'example link' will be editable.

Comment: Thank you! Ended up using format helper to generate the HTML but this is a great solution.